# Google Apps Script and cookies

Tags: cookies, google-apps-script

I am trying to Post and get a cookie.  I am a newbie and this is a learning project for me.  My impression is that if you use 'set-cookie' one should be able to see an additional 'set-cookie' in the .toSource.  (I am trying to accomplish this on Google Apps Site if that makes a difference.) Am I missing something?  Here is my code:

```
 function setGetCookies() {

  var payload = {'set-cookie' : 'test'};
  var opt2 = {'headers':payload, "method":"post"};

  UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://sites.google.com/a/example.com/blacksmith", opt2);
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://sites.google.com/a/example.com/blacksmith")

  var openId = response.getAllHeaders().toSource();
  Logger.log(openId)      

  var AllHeaders =  response.getAllHeaders();
  for (var prop in AllHeaders) {
    if (prop.toLowerCase() == "set-cookie") {
      // if there's only one cookie, convert it into an array:
      var myArray = [];
      if ( Array.isArray(AllHeaders[prop]) ) {
        myArray=AllHeaders[prop];
      } else {
        myArray[0]=AllHeaders[prop];
      }
      // now process the cookies
      myArray.forEach(function(cookie) {  
         Logger.log(cookie);
      });
      break;
    }
  }

}
```

Thanks in advance!  I referenced this to develop the code: [Cookie handling in Google Apps Script - How to send cookies in header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10869932/cookie-handling-in-google-apps-script-how-to-send-cookies-in-header)

Open to any advice.

Answer (score 1):

When you aren't logged in Google Sites won't set any cookies in the response. UrlFetchApp doesn't pass along your Google cookies, so it will behave as if you are logged out.

Answer (score 0):

First the cookie you want to send whose name is 'test' does not have a value. You should send 'test=somevalue'.

Second I am wondering if you are trying to send the cookie to the googlesite server and ask it to reply with the same cookie you previously sent... ?

I am thinking you are trying to act as a HTTP server beside you are a HTTP client.
As a HTTP client your role is only to send back any cookies that the HTTP server have previously sent to you (respecting the domain, expiration... params).